# Malloc misallocation?

Tags: c

new to C programmer here. This code runs beautifully when the training set it small, but it starts to crash when the range increases. Right now it breaks at 1289, but I'd like to use it up to 7892.  The error is below; I'm fairly certain it's related to something in the malloc call, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Thanks.

```
TrainSet* get_train_set(float range){
   TrainSet* t; 
   printf("%f\n", range);
   t =  malloc(range * sizeof *t);
   FILE *fp;
   char line[300]; /* 300 is an arbitrary length to read in lines from the text file*/
   int count = 0;
   fp = fopen("Data/main_training_set.txt", "r");
   if(fp == NULL){
      perror("Error opening file");
      return NULL;
   }
   while (fgets(line, 300, fp)){
      // printf("%d\n", count);
      int s = strlen((line)) - 3;
      char* quote = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * s);
      for(int i = 0; i <= s; i++){
         quote[i] = line[i];
      }
      int label =  atoi(&line[s]);
      t->sentences[count] = quote;
      t->labels[count] = label;
      count ++;
   }
   //fclose(fp);
   return t;
}
```

The error:

```
buddhism: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

And here's the h file for TrainSet

```
typedef struct TrainSet {
    char* sentences[7892];
    int labels[7892];
} TrainSet;

TrainSet* get_train_set(float range);

#endif /* READ_H*/*
```

Input data is essentially this, a garbled sort of sentence with an integer at the end of every line.

```
first four lectures taking place weekendand subject weekends talk five aggregates 1
relationship us thats simply want tobe happy dont want suffer 1
heard words songrecently said "i dont mind dying living scaresme 1
us know difficulties life trying somehowto minimize 1
```

Comment: Looks like you have a memory corruption somewhere. It's hard for us to help unless a [mcve] is provided. But for starters `for(int i = 0; i <= s; i++)` causes out of bound access. It needs to be `for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)`. If that doesn't help then suggest running [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help find the memory corruption.

Comment: Look into using [getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) instead of fgets. No arbitrary memory allocation necessary.

Comment: @Schwern That function may not be available on non-POSIX systems

Comment: Using a floating point value for `range` in the size calculation for `malloc()` is very unusual.  Not necessarily wrong, but unusual enough to be a cause for concern.  What is that meant to do?  How is it used?  Why isn't it an appropriate size of integer rather than a `float`?

Comment: You allocated memory for `s` characters, and then copied `s+1` characters into that memory. And didn't NUL terminate the string either. You're also assuming that the `strlen(line)` is more than 3. Basically, you need to take a step back, and come up with a sensible plan to parse the input.

Comment: Could you show us the `TrainSet` definition please?

Comment: @M.M Worth it. If it's not available, make your own.

Comment: Does `t =  malloc(range * sizeof *t);` make sense when `t` is not used as an array?

Comment: Thanks everybody!! I'll try to answer your very thoughtful points. For starters, @kaylum was absolutely correct, and that has already been extremely helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't `range * sizeof *t` be calculated as `float`?  Even if `range` always holds an integer value, there might not be enough precision if `sizeof(TrainSet)` is fairly large..

Comment: @Schwern: Probably not. (To be pedantic, when `t` is not used as a pointer to the initial element of an array.) `get_train_set` only initializes the `TrainSet` object that `t` points to, not any of its successors. (And the floating-point `range` is very suspicious.)

Comment: what does your input data look like - its hard to picture it

Comment: @Dmitri: Yes, `range * sizeof *t` yields a `float` result -- which is implicitly converted to `size_t` before being passed to `malloc`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I use the range for division later, where the type has to be a float.

Comment: can we please see the definition of TrainSet

Comment: With `TrainSet` containing the two 7892-element arrays, `range * sizeof *t` probably won't be exact if `range` is more than a few hundred, even if `range` is always an exact integer value.  `float` normally only has 24-bits of precision..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing past the end of `quote` and potentially writing past the end of `t`.

This loop:

```
  for(int i = 0; i <= s; i++){
     quote[i] = line[i];
  }
```

writes one `char` past  the end of `quote`.

And this part:

```
  t->sentences[count] = quote;
  t->labels[count] = label;
```

does not check if `count < range`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @MSN! The strange thing is that this worked perfectly at a smaller size, which now that I'm looking at it I can't see why it would have. You were absolutely correct.

Comment: I believe the reason why you probably didn't notice is because accessing out of bounds of arrays in C is considered undefined behavior, so God knows what actually is written to.

Answer (score 3):

```
  char* quote = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * s);
  for(int i = 0; i <= s; i++){
     quote[i] = line[i];
  }
```

Suppose `s` is 2. Your `for` loop will loop over 0, 1, and 2. That's three spaces in `quote`. But since `s` is 2, you've only allocated space in `quote` for two.

Comment: @user3386109 Maybe, but then it's hard to explain why he allocated `s` spaces, copied (roughly) `s` characters and passed `atoi` a pointer to `line[s]`. You'd think there'd be a -3 in there somewhere. But with no comments (other than one unhelpful one) and many errors, it's awfully hard to be sure.

Comment: Ahh, you are right. It makes much more sense now. Good catch. (Updating answer.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the s logic is used to grab an integer that's at the end of every single quote, and add it to a separate list of labels. The quotes need to be added to a list of quotes. Thanks for the advice! Female writer, btw.